# React ES6, How to keep decorators in separate files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babel-decorator

We have created lots decorator in ReactApp.

Now we have to write decorators in every file, My typical Code look something like this.

******** **MyComponent.js** *************

```
import {Decorators} from 'decoratorLib';
import React, {Component} from 'react';

const {ModuleLoader, ModuleConfig, log} = Decorators;

@ModuleLoader({
    config: {
        k1: 'Value 1',
        k2: 'Value 2',
        viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
        ...moduleConfig
    },

    propTypes: {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        age: PropTypes.number,
        address: PropTypes.string,
        quantity: PropTypes.number
    }
})

@ModuleConfig({
    config: {
        k1: 'Value 1',
        k2: 'Value 2',
        viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
        ...moduleConfig
    }
})

@log({
    config: {
        warning: true,
        error: true,
        breakOnError:false
    }
})
class MyComponent extends Component {

}
```

I am wondering How, we can write these decorators in a sperate file and then write some bridge to pass/connect with classes

Like I can have a **decorators.js** file, write all decorators here and then write some method or injector to inject these in classes.

Comment: The stuff after the `@` is just a value like anything else. You can assign it to a variable then use the variable in its place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decorators are just values, so you can change your code to

```
const loaderDecorator = ModuleLoader({
    config: {
        k1: 'Value 1',
        k2: 'Value 2',
        viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
        ...moduleConfig
    },

    propTypes: {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        age: PropTypes.number,
        address: PropTypes.string,
        quantity: PropTypes.number
    }
});

const configDecorator = ModuleConfig({
    config: {
        k1: 'Value 1',
        k2: 'Value 2',
        viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
        ...moduleConfig
    }
});

const logDecorator = log({
    config: {
        warning: true,
        error: true,
        breakOnError:false
    }
});

@loaderDecorator
@configDecorator
@logDecorator
class MyComponent extends Component { }
```

and at that point you're free to move those variables to any file you want, then import them into this file to use them, e.g.

```
import { loaderDecorator, configDecorator, logDecorator } from './my-decorators';

@loaderDecorator
@configDecorator
@logDecorator
class MyComponent extends Component { }
```

with

```
export const loaderDecorator = ModuleLoader({
    config: {
        k1: 'Value 1',
        k2: 'Value 2',
        viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
        ...moduleConfig
    },

    propTypes: {
        name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
        age: PropTypes.number,
        address: PropTypes.string,
        quantity: PropTypes.number
    }
});

export const configDecorator = ModuleConfig({
    config: {
        k1: 'Value 1',
        k2: 'Value 2',
        viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
        ...moduleConfig
    }
});

export const logDecorator = log({
    config: {
        warning: true,
        error: true,
        breakOnError:false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Decorator is actually a function

```
@decorator1(args)
@decorator2(args)
class Decorated {}
```

is just function composition and application

```
Decorated = decorator1(args)(decorator2(args)(Decorated))
```

So you could compose all your decorators beforehand

```
// decorators.js
const compose = (fns...) => init => fns.reduceRight((res, fn) => fn(res), init)

export default compose(
    ModuleLoader({
        config: {
            k1: 'Value 1',
            k2: 'Value 2',
            viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
            ...moduleConfig
        },

        propTypes: {
            name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
            age: PropTypes.number,
            address: PropTypes.string,
            quantity: PropTypes.number
        }
    }),
    ModuleConfig({
        config: {
            k1: 'Value 1',
            k2: 'Value 2',
            viewClass: ModuleViewClass,
            ...moduleConfig
        }
    }),
    log({
        config: {
            warning: true,
            error: true,
            breakOnError: false
        }
    })
)
```

and then just

```
import decorate from './decorators'

@decorate
class MyComponent extends Component {

}
```

Comment: Just Wondering, how can I define, like for "Class1" I need only 2 decorators "D1" & "D2". For another class "Class2", I need another set of decorators like "D1", "D3" & "D4"

Comment: @AnupSingh Same way you could do for normal functions: either define a higher order function that takes some arguments and returns a decorator, or precompose those two options before hand and export them with descriptive names.